# Angular 4 how to push entire tr in table

Tags: angular

I am playing around with Angular 4, but could not find the right answer on the internet. So was wondering if someone here has the knowledge to help me out a bit. Want to push an entire new table row to this table. I want 2 rows of four items instead of one row.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'First Angular Assignment';
  balances: string[];

  constructor() {
   this.balances = [
        "Zorgtoeslag", "60", "Verzekering", "80", /* first row*/
         "Zorgtoeslag", "60", "Verzekering", "80",  /* second row and so on */ 
      ];
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <th>Inkomsten</th>
     <th></th>
     <th>Uitgaven</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td *ngFor = "let balance of balances;">
         {{balance}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have to correct you object like `this.balances = [
        {"Zorgtoeslag", "60", "Verzekering", "80"}, /* first row*/
         {"Zorgtoeslag", "60", "Verzekering", "80"}  /* second row and so on */ 
      ];`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5NdLSa7ljlYagaVALq4?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui I got the following error in console.log --> The pipe 'chunks' could not be found

Comment: You need to add ChunkPipe to declarations array

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a collection for your data as shown in the constructor, However you can bring to the specifc format using the below code

```
this.data = [];

for(let i =0 ;i<this.balances.length; i+=4){
      this.data.push({Inkomsten : this.balances[i] d1 :this.balances[i+1],
      Verzekering :this.balances[i+2],d2:this.balances[i+3]})
    }
}

    <tr *ngFor = "let d of data">
        <td>{{d.Inkomsten}}</td>
        <td>{{d.d1}}</td>
        <td>{{d.Verzekering }}</td>
        <td>{{d.d2}}</td>
    </tr>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/catfvC79xeflkZigwU2M?p=preview)**

Comment: Could you add some demo to this

Comment: That is not four on row what I meant

Comment: added data: string[]; to "export class AppComponent", but got the following error Argument of type '{ Inkomsten: string; Verzekering: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: reach me in fb @ aravind2109

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class AppComponent {
title = 'First Angular Assignment';
balances : [{
   costdesc: string,
   cost: Number,
   expensedesc: string,
   expense: Number
  }];
  constructor() {
   this.balances = [{
    costdesc: "Salaris",
    cost: 2200,
    expensedesc: "Boodschappen",
    expense: 300
   },
   {
    costdesc: "Zorgtoeslag",
    cost: 60,
    expensedesc: "Verzekering",
    expense: 80
   },
   {
    costdesc: null,
    cost: null,
    expensedesc: "Telefoon",
    expense: 30
   },
   {
    costdesc: null,
    cost: null,
    expensedesc: "Hypotheek",
    expense: 400
   },
   {
    costdesc: null,
    cost: null,
    expensedesc: "TV/Internet",
    expense: 40
   }];
  }
}
```

```html
 <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Inkomsten</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Uitgaven</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let balance of balances">
         <td>{{balance.costdesc}}</td>
         <td>{{balance.cost}}</td>
         <td>{{balance.expensedesc}}</td>
         <td>{{balance.expense}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```